# Core Data NSPredicate search in multiple Attributes columns

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate

I want to search keywords in Hotels Entity in two attributes (hotelName & cityName)

i'm looking for hotel [image]

"**The Kensington Studios**" is in hotelName Attribute

"**London**" is cityName Attribute

in search bar, if i type middle of the hotelName and cityName(just like below) it should identify and display the results. [image]

to achieve this, i'm doing like

```
let charSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ") 
let words = searchText.components(separatedBy: charSet) 
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(hotelName IN %@) OR (cityName IN %@)", words, words)
```

But its giving empty results.

Please guide me..

Comment: Does it work if you type the whole word from the hotel name, i.e. "Kensington" instead of "Kensing"?

Comment: Check the answer below, Lokesh. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

words object returns [String] array. You have to use each object of the array. So the code should be like

```html
let words = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ")
        
        var predicateArr = [NSPredicate]()
        for word in words! {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(hotelName contains [c]) OR (cityName contains [c])", word, word)
            predicateArr.append(predicate)
        }
        
        
        let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateArr)
        let output = array.filtered(using: compound)
```